# Where is Castbox saving the downloads?

Tags: podcast

Installing the podcast manager [Castbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fm.castbox.audiobook.radio.podcast&hl=fr), it has a setting to chose downloads location between internal and external card, but I cannot find them with a file manager. I would like to just copy/paste them on my computer and keep a copy (without the need to download them again on the computer).

Maybe are they trying to avoid the saving of the files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They saved the file on sdcard > CastBox > channels > xxx > yyy
or on sdcard>Android>data>fm.castbox.audiobook>files>channels>xxx>‌​yyy

xxx is folder of channel usually the unique number of each channel, yyy is file name. But, they stored it without extention of the file, so you cannot play it.

Trick to play it, just rename the file name. Add extention .mp3 on the name.
Example: filename= 24234234
Rename it to 24234234.mp3

Comment: Thank you for your answer which put me on the good path. In fact this may by version-specific. On this Marshmallow the location is different (you could add that to your answer and I'll mark it as the solution): `sdcard>Android>data>fm.castbox.audiobook>files>channels>xxx>yyy`.  But what's more, I was able to reach the files with ES Explorer in Android but not with the file manager of my computer (`fm.castbox.audiobook` is simply absent there). If I copy one of the files in a different location that my computer normally can access, the file is not accessible by computer.

Comment: For the given purpose Castbox is not the best solution. If one must use it in order to transfer a podcast audio file from the phone to a computer, the easiest way that I can see is this: Castbox provides a "share" button for each selected file; sharing it provides a link `http://castbox.fm` where the podcast can be played and captured/downloaded with a dedicated tool (flashgot, Flash Video Downloader etc)

Comment: nice sharing, we can do more if we use computer,

Comment: I think there is no use in renaming the file: it can be played without that by android players (in my experience), but there is no way of knowing which file it is before playing it; it also cannot be used effectively but through the Castbox application (such files are NOT accessible by computer).